# TypeScript casting with modules

Tags: node.js, casting, module, typescript

How can I cast the type of a variable with an exported class? Such as this:

GameManager.ts:

```
export class GameManager {}
```

Player.ts:

```
private _manager: GameManager;
```

when i use a `/// <reference path="GameManager.ts" />`, i get an error saying GameManager is out of scope or something like that. How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 5):

There are several cases here, depending on where the `export class GameManager {}` line is:

Option 1: You're using "external" modules (i.e. you have any `export` declarations at top-level).

In this case, you should remove the `reference` tag and instead write:

```
import Manager = module("GameManager"); // N.B. this is the filename, not the class name
...
private _manager: Manager.GameManager;
```

Option 2: You're using "internal" modules (i.e. your `export class` is inside a `module` block, but not an `export module` block)

In that case, you should keep your `/// <reference...` tag and write:

```
private _manager: MyGame.Manager; // N.B. Assuming here that 'GameManager' lives inside 'module MyGame { ... }'
```

It might be that you don't actually want the `export` keyword on your class - if you do that, you don't need to qualify it at all (assuming there's nothing else at top-level being exported).

Comment: ok, i do this, and now I get weird "property does not exist" errors. `The property sendToAllButOrigin' does not exist on value of type "GameManager"`
`

Answer (score 1):

For an internal module you have to wrap the exported class in a module, so the GameManager.ts file should be:

```
module Game
{
    export class GameManager{}
}
```

Now you can access the GameManager class through

```
Game.GameManager
```